# Swap Nodes in Pairs

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, swap

I am currently brushing up and reviewing my datastructures as I prepare for job interviews.  I am currently working on this problem where I have to swap every 2 nodes in a Linked List.  My code is as follows:

```
public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0); 
    dummy.next = head;
    while (head != null && head.next != null){
        ListNode cur = head;
        ListNode prev = head.next;
        head = prev;
        head.next = cur;
        head.next.next = prev.next;
        head = prev.next;

    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

This gives me an infinite loop for some reason even though my logic seems to be very sound to me.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: 1) What if head.next.next does not exist? and only head.next exists?  2) Never modify the parameter to the function, i.e head. Use a temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already lost the later elements of the list.

If your list was 1->2->3

First

```
    curr=1
    prev=head.next=2
```

Now

```
    head = prev; head=2

    head.next = cur; head.next=1
```

Here you have modified prev.next. So prev.next is basically 1

This below statement is now causing a loop

```
    head.next.next = prev.next;
```

**This way, you've lost your access to 3**
The while loop is infinite as it is basically stuck in the first two numbers

Store the 3rd element before you reverse the first two